# User location image pin disappears most of time

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

i Am using following code

```
-(MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    if ([[annotation title] isEqualToString:@"Current Location"] )
    {
        MKAnnotationView *anView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"currentPin"];

        anView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pin_green.png"];
        anView.canShowCallout = true;
        anView.enabled = true;
        return anView;
    }
```

The issue is, it randomly disappears and appears again. Giving a very bad user experience. Any way to fix this?

Comment: This piece of code is not the problem, obviously. The problem should be with the fact that you're removing all the annotations at some point of time and adding them again

Comment: @Eugene such a stupid mistake. i am feeling embarrased. Thanks for pointing out. Fixed that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several suspect things about this code:

- You're not using `dequeue`, as someone has pointed out. In particular, the problem here is that you are making a new view every single time, rather than checking to see whether a new view needs making.
- You are forgetting the key step, namely, to associate the view with the annotation.

Here is the canonical structure of a simple `viewForAnnotation:` implementation where we supply our own view:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView
            viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation {
    MKAnnotationView* v = nil;
    if ([annotation.title isEqualToString:@"Current Location"]) {
        static NSString* ident = @"greenPin";
        v = [mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:ident];
        if (v == nil) {
            v = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation
                                              reuseIdentifier:ident];
            v.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pin_green.png"];
            v.canShowCallout = YES;
        }
        v.annotation = annotation;
    }
    return v;
}
```

Since that code works for me, I'd suggest you start with it and tweak it as necessary.

By the way, you do NOT need this method just to get a green pin! You do know that, right? iOS will give you a green pin (MKPinAnnotationColorGreen).

Answer (score 0):

You should use MKMapView's `dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:` and see if you get a view back before creating a new one with `initWithAnnotation:reuseIdentifier:`:

```
MKAnnotationView *anView = [mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"currentPin"];

if (!anView) {
    anView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"currentPin"];

    anView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pin_green.png"];
    anView.canShowCallout = true;
    anView.enabled = true;
}

return anView;
```

That said, I'm not entirely sure this is the cause of your problem.